# JAVA - CXF WS-security "A security error was encountered when verifying the message"

Tags: java, soap, cxf, ws-security

Sorry for this question, it can appear recurrent by I'm completely blocked.
I'm trying to implement a Web Service Server on top of **CXF** framework. **Jax-ws** is very helpful to handle a web service, it's easy to implement  it.
But, the problem come when you want to introduce **security**.

To handle security in implement the following source code :

```
EndpointImpl jaxWsEndpoint = (EndpointImpl) Endpoint.publish(endPointAddress, httpWebService);
inProps.put("action", "UsernameToken Timestamp");
inProps.put("passwordType", "PasswordText");
inProps.put("passwordCallbackClass", "com.company.webService.PasswordListener");
jaxWsEndpoint.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps));
```

I push to this Web Service the following **SOAP** request :

```
...
<soapenv:Header>
   <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wsse:Usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-27777511" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:Usernametoken>
   </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
...
```

The **CXF** framework received my request try to handle the security part and throw me the following exception:

```
Jun 08, 2016 10:48:24 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor checkActions
WARNING: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
Jun 08, 2016 10:48:24 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://httpAbstractHandlerImplementation.webService.company.co /}HttpWebServiceService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: A security error was encountered when verifying the message at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JUtils.createSoapFault(WSS4JUtils.java:218)
at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:316)
```

If somebody have an idea where i have done an error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have `inProps.put("action", "UsernameToken Timestamp");` but no Timestamp in your security header. Either remove "Timestamp" from your actions or add the matching security header.

**EDIT**
The message is quite clear "Security processing failed **(actions mismatch)**" So looking at your request reveals another mistake: It should be `wsse:UsernameToken` instead of `wsse:Usernametoken` as of the [official spec](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/13392/wss-v1.1-spec-pr-UsernameTokenProfile-01.htm#_Toc104276210).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I already try this, without success. Unfortunately i have the same exception.

Comment: Two questions: Which versions of cxf and wss4j are you using and what exactly did you try? Remove the action or add a timestamp? If the latter: did you check the order of the headers? It is essential that the order of security headers is exactly as the InInterceptor expects.

Comment: So I use **CXF** version 3.1.6 . And to answer to your question I removed "Timestamp" from the properties container

Comment: To add details for your comprehension,  My application is a POJO standalone application , I'm not using High level framework like Spring, Tomecat etc..

Comment: OH many thanks , sorry for this misteak..let's go for the an other exception : 
Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: BSP:R4201: Any PASSWORD MUST specify a Type attribute

Comment: Same as with the UsernameToken: `Type` not `type`... Perhaps you should use something like SoapUI to generate your requests for you?

Comment: GREAT!!!  My Call back is called!! Really many thanks..  Now i need to understand wha t i need to implement in this callback

Comment: My Web Service working well now , Many thanks again.