# Username Token Validation Error

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm working on a project which uses a CXF SoapMessage generated form a
string. I'm trying use Username Token Validation but it throws
**NullPointerException**.

This is the source code [1] I used. I pass a SOAP message [2] as a
string to **initiateComplianceCheck** method and it then converts it into a CXF SoapMessage object and use it for Username Token authentication.

[1] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bfb6f65194a030a50681af175a9937f5

[2] https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f704db6147e02acdff323dc67ccff6d6

But CXF handleMessage gives a NullPointerException

This is a part of the error message thrown

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at
org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterc
eptor.java:165)
```

Appreciate if you can help me to solve this issue

Comment: I think you should provide more information. Not many people use CXF so we need more like the version of the library. [Check also this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37698141/java-cxf-ws-security-a-security-error-was-encountered-when-verifying-the-mess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE is because there is no Message Exchange set on the SoapMessage. you could add in the following to your code:

```
Exchange ex = new ExchangeImpl();
ex.setInMessage(message);
```

example:

https://github.com/apache/cxf/blob/3.1.x-fixes/rt/ws/security/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/ws/security/wss4j/WSS4JInOutTest.java

By the way, the wsse namespace I'm using in the sample is from a very
old standard and won't work. It should be xmlns:wsse="
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
instead.